# DataContractSerializer - Ignore nulls in an array

Tags: .net, datacontractserializer

I have an array of Objects, which may contain null values.

When serializing the array, I am also getting an empty tag to represent the null value. Ex.

```
<TableType i:nil="true" />
<TableType i:nil="true" />
<TableType i:nil="true" />
```

How can I serialize without these values?

Answer (score 0):

One approach I can think of is to user XmlWriter and trim the ones with nil...

Answer (score 0):

In your DataMember declaration, all the optional parameter EmitDefaultValues = false;

DataMember( IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false )